# Send message data from web project to WebView using JS

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, webview

I am new in web project and webview communication , so I don't know how the send a message from web project that has been loaded in the React Native Webview.
I need to send some message from my web project (Php/Laravel) to the webview.

Here is the example of code I am using.

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "{{ route('register-step-seven') }}",
                    data: $("#step-7 form").serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        if ($.isEmptyObject(data.error) && $.isEmptyObject(data.password_error)) {
                            if(data.data){
                                **window.postMessage(data.data);**
                                **window.parent.postMessage(data.data);**



                            }

                            **setTimeout(function (){
                                window.postMessage(data.data);
                                window.location.href = "{{route('dashboard')}}";
                            }, 1000);**


                        } else {
                            

                            if (data.error) {
                                printErrorMsg(data.error);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });
```

Non of the mentioned  line code is not working, I can not see the tost popup in React.

And the other point - will message send work, if I will send it and then redirect the page by `window.location.href`?

Answer (score 0):

After lot of researches, I found this, that solved my problem .
As the mobile was written on React Native, insted of doing just `window.postMessage(data.data,"*");` need to do `"window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("test message");"`

```
function isInWebView() {
    // Check if the user agent contains the keywords commonly used by web views
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    return (
        userAgent.indexOf('wv') > -1 ||     // Android WebView
        userAgent.indexOf('x-webview') > -1 // iOS UIWebView or WKWebView
    );
}

// // Usage
if (isInWebView()) {
    // Website is being viewed within a web view
   alert('Website is in a web view');
    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("test message");
} else {
    // Website is being viewed in a browser
    alert('Website is in a browser');
}
```